# Is grammatically possible and natural to say "I wish you weren't doing" and "I wish you wouldn't be doing"?

Tags: grammar

Is grammatically possible and natural to say *I wish you weren't doing* and *I wish you wouldn't be doing*? For example:

> I wish you **weren't smoking**.
>
> I wish you **wouldn't be smoking**.

If it is possible and natural, then what would be the difference in meaning between them and the following?

> I wish you **didn't smoke**.
>
> I wish you **wouldn't smoke**.

Comment: In all fairness, you can get a grammar lesson about wish in tons of places. Why makes us write it all out when it's easily found elsewhere?? For example, here: https://www.english-at-home.com/grammar/using-wish/#:~:text=The%20verb%20after%20%E2%80%9Cwish%E2%80%9D%20is,%E2%80%9Cwish%E2%80%9D%20is%20past%20perfect.

Comment: I am not sure what is the difference among the first two sentences (in block-quote) however the second one is as follows: "didn't smoke" indicates that the person is smoking right in front of you, and you were saying them on their face. Whereas, "wouldn't smoke" probably means something that could possibly happen in the future. In this case, something that you wish would happen in the near future.

Comment: Lambie: if you would be kind enouh to provide the place on the internet that answers my question, I would be grateful. I couldn't find such a place. And, the one you provided doesn't answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wish you weren't smoking.

Perfectly grammatical and natural.  The person is smoking *at the present moment* and you wish they weren't.

> I wish you wouldn't be smoking.

This is non-standard and odd sounding.

> I wish you didn't smoke.

The person smokes on a regular basis but may or may not be smoking at the present moment.  You wish they didn't have this habit.

> I wish you wouldn't smoke.

Used similarly to the first, but can also be used if the person has just finished smoking.